# Is it possible to Import .sql file into database from external url using php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder if it is possible to import .sql file into database from external url using laravel by the function `DB::unprepared`,

Like we do to import .sql from the same server as `DB::unprepared(file_get_contents($sql_path));`

but can i import using url(`http://website.com/import.sql`) ? instead of the **same server path?**

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes, what happened? If not, why not?

Comment: yes i have tried but not working 500 error .. i don't know the reason.. might be it because when you click the http://website.com/import.sql it will download you the import.sql file so it's die there itself so i think it's not working ... but hope some body got an idea.

Comment: you should probably just grab a copy of the file to the local storage, import, then destroy the file afterwards.

Comment: yes i did that now it's working carm!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('http://weebsite/import.sql'));
```

this line is enough for the action.